# Cambiar clase de Bootstrap dependiendo de la resolución de pantalla

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Tengo un problema con una clases de bootstrap, tengo un div de clase .row y dentro de dicho div tengo dos mas con clases .col-10 y col-2, al momento de ejecutarse la aplicación en Desktop se ve bien, pero al pasarlo a la resolución del iPad, se sobreponen los div.

Lo intento hacer es que cuando la resolución de la pantalla sea de 768px(width) la clase de .col-10 cambie a .col-12 para que ocupe la pantalla completa y el otro div baje.

Intente hacer una función de JavaScript pero no me manda error ni nada y no hace el cambio que necesito.

```
function cambio(){
    var clase = document.getElementById("resize");
  if (window.screen.width < 768){
    clase.className = "col-12";
  }else{
    clase.className = "col-10";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Respecto a tu pregunta, estas mal enfocando el sistema de grillas de bootstrap,
para lo que quieres hacer no es necesario **javascript**.
Resulta que para lo que quieres solo necesitas usar las clases de `col-*`.

Entrando un poco mas a detalle, los breakpoint de bootstrap este las define como
`col-sm-* , col-md-* , col-lg-* , col-xl-*` [Grid Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#grid-options). 
Siendo en ese orden (menor a mayor, a excepción de `col-*` ya que no tiene breakpoint, ***por eso es no funciona tu código***)

Entonces **¿Cómo hago para que tenga cierto tamaño según el dispositivo?**

La respuesta es sencilla solo usas las clase en el `div` para que funcione, ejemplo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-8 col-xl-4 border">
      Soy un div adaptable!!!
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-4 col-xl-8 border">
      Soy un div adaptable!!!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

En ese snnipet le estoy diciendo que según el dispositivo ocupe cierto porcentaje de del row, si miras bien `col-sm-4` esta clase `col-sm` se usa para dispositivos pequeños por ejemplo celulares, `col-md-*` generalmente se usa para tablet, `col-lg-*` se usa generalmente para pantallas de Computadoras y `col-xl-*` para pantallas con resolución sobre los `1140px`, por eso solo debes usar las clases y la pantalla se adaptará sola.

El total de grillas que maneja son 1 a 12, y cada número tiene un porcentaje siendo el 12 el que representa el 100% del total de ancho del `row`.

Resumiendo entonces uso `sm, md, lg, xl` dependiendo de como quiero que se comporte por dispositivo y uso número de 1 al 12 para decir que porcentaje uso.

Espero que te ayude esta explicación. Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

Utiliza:

```
col-sm- para Samll  > = 576px
col-md- para medium  > = 720px
col-lg- para large > = 992px
col-xl- para Extra large > = 1200px
```

Por ejemplo:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Más información en : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/

Comment: Ya esta listo lo solucione, con col-sm-12 y un col-lg-10 para uno y para el otro col-sm-12 y col-lg-2 muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

La ventaja del framework boostrap es que maneja el [sistema de rejillas(grid system).](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) El cual te apoya para que tu web trabaje con [diseño responsivo (resposive desing)](https://programarfacil.com/blog/crear-una-web-responsive-con-bootstrap/). El cual conciste en adapatarse al tamaño de la pantalla, como lo que buscas.

```
<div class="resize col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-10"></div>
```

Esto es lo que buscas hacer con tu código.

Enfocaque a estudiar el grid system y los prefijos de pantalla de boostrap que van de la mano.

Answer (score -1):

Utiliza CSS media queries.

Agrupa por tamaño min. o max. según corresponda.

Antes de ello, verifica la estandarización que usa Bootstrap para calcular los límites.

```
col-sm- para Samll  > = 576px
col-md- para medium  > = 720px
col-lg- para large > = 992px
col-xl- para Extra large > = 1200px
```

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]